# Do primes modulo k form a normal sequence?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, ergodic-theory

For some $k>2$, form a sequence whose nth term is the nth prime that is not a divisor of $k$ modulo $k$.

e.g. for $k=4$ the sequence would be 1,3,1,3,3,1,1,3,3,1,3,1...

Is this sequence normal, in the sense that every string of length $w$ consisting of numbers in $\{1..k\}$ coprime to $k$ occurs as a block of consecutive terms with asymptotic density $\frac{1}{\phi(k)^w}$?

Note that the case $w=1$ is equivalent to Dirichlet's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that this is known, although it is conjectured to be true (and would surely follow, for example, from the Hardy-Littlewood prime $k$-tuples conjecture). There has been research into getting constellations of primes in particular residue classes, but it's hard to ensure that you get *consecutive* primes in the right residue classes. Some important earlier work is by Daniel Shiu, I believe; it's possible, using the recent Maynard/Tao techniques, that somebody might have made some progress.

Comment: Can you cite a reference where this is conjectured to be true? It seems to me that the $k$-tuples conjecture implies it is *not* true, and that seems to be borne out empirically.

Comment: I'm surprised by both parts of your comment, Zander - can you elaborate?

Comment: The $k$-tuples conjecture says gaps of $2,6,10,14,18$ are more likely than gaps of $4,8,12,16,20$, so early on $(1,3),(3,1)$ should be more likely than $(1,1),(3,3)$. For the first billion terms with $k=4$ there are about 20% more $(1,3),(3,1)$ than $(1,1),(3,3)$. It is confounded that gaps of $24,36$ are more common than gaps of $22,34$, so it's possible that the differences work out in the limit, but in order for it to be normal it would have to be that prime pairs with difference $2\pmod 4$ were exactly as common as with $0\pmod 4$, which I'd find a bit surprising.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now, and can articulate why I disagree. Any finite number of gaps occur with density zero among the primes (proved by Brun). The gaps that are relevant to the asymptotic densities of strings of consecutive primes near $x$ are the gaps of size comparable to $\log x$; smaller gaps just disappear in the limit. Of course, $\log x$ grows slowly and so for small numbers, there is a bias as you note - but I believe that will go away. (I feel like Goldston proved something along these lines.)

Comment: Do you mean "I believe this is not known"?